# Romans 16:20 what is the meaning of 'under your feet'?

Tags: romans, eschatology, satan

> The God of peace will soon crush Satan under your feet.

The last letter to the Roman church with lots of greetings and encouragements. And a few warnings.

Immediate context is;

> 17 Now I urge you, brothers and sisters, keep your eye on those who cause dissensions and hindrances contrary to the teaching which you learned, and turn away from them. 18 For such people are slaves, not of our Lord Christ but of their own appetites; and by their smooth and flattering speech they deceive the hearts of the unsuspecting. 19 For the report of your obedience has reached everyone; therefore I am rejoicing over you, but I want you to be wise in what is good, and innocent in what is evil. 20 **The God of peace will soon crush Satan under your feet.**

How is the church involved in this final victory?

Answer (score 1):

**Romans 16:20 what is the meaning of 'under your feet'?**

Romans 16:20 NASB

> 20 The God of peace will soon crush Satan under your feet.

Satan is abyssed for a thousand years, after which he suffers complete annihilation in “the lake of fire.”Rev. 20:14 "Then Death and Hades were thrown into the lake of fire. **This is the second death, the lake of fire ."**

Revelation 20:1-2,10 NASB

Satan Bound

> 20 Then I saw an angel coming down from heaven, holding the key of the
> abyss and a great chain [a]in his hand. 2 And he took hold of the
> dragon, the serpent of old, who is the devil and Satan, and bound him
> for a thousand years; 10 And the devil who deceived them was thrown
> into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false
> prophet are also; and they will be tormented day and night forever and
> ever.

Paul used the expression under your feet figuratively to denote that they [Jesus resurrected spiritual brothers} would share with Jesus in the crushing of Satan.​

> Rom. 16: 20 The God of peace will soon **crush Satan under your feet.**

> Gen. 3:15 And I will make enemies  Of you and the woman,  And of your
> offspring and her Descendant [Jesus];  He shall bruise you on the
> head,  And you shall bruise Him on the heel.”

Answer (score 0):

Rom 16:20 appears to be an allusion to Gen 3:15 -

> And I will put enmity Between you and the woman, And between your seed
> and her Seed; He shall bruise your head, And you shall bruise His
> heel.”

Thus, the Messianic prophecy of gen 3:15 is a reference to both the crucifixion of Messiah and His apparent temporary defeat, vs the final destruction Satan as prophesied in Rev 20.  Note the comments of Barnes on Rom 16:20 -

> **Will bruise** - The "language" here refers to the prediction in Genesis
> 3:15. It here means to "subdue, to gain the victory over." It denotes
> Paul's confidence that they "would" gain the victory, and would be
> able to overcome all the arts of those who were endeavoring to sow
> discord and contention among them.

Answer (score 0):

The struggle started in Gen 3 when God spoke to the serpent:

> 15 And I will put enmity Between you and the woman, And between your seed and her Seed; He shall bruise your **head**, And you shall bruise His heel.”

The struggle will end when

> Psalm 110:1 The LORD says to my lord: "Sit at my right hand until I make your enemies a footstool for your **feet**."

> Matthew 22:44
> The Lord said to my Lord, "Sit at My right hand until I put Your enemies under Your **feet**."'

Paul understood that that was the fate of Satan. In Ephesians 6:15, he spoke of

> and with your **feet** fitted with the readiness that comes from the gospel of **peace**.

Here Paul wrote in the ending passage of Roman verse 20:

> The God of **peace** will soon crush Satan under your **feet**.

In the end, Satan will be under our feet and we will enjoy lasting peace.

Romans 16:20 what is the meaning of 'under your feet'?

Paul wrote about all the struggles experienced by the church in Rome. In the ending chapter, Paul encouraged the people to look to the promised future of lasting peace when Satan is crushed under our feet, no longer movable.